# error TS2322: Type '(e: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(payload: Event) => void'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a code in template like this

```
<my-component @select="onSelect" />

// js
methods: {
    async onSelect(e: string) {
       // do something with e:string
    }
}
```

but the ts compiler throwing error

```
error TS2322: Type '(e: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(payload: Event) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'payload' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: change `string` to `Event` in `onSelect` arg

Comment: No, my-component is emitting string and I want a string here to run some string methods

Comment: Please show the code where you define the emit events on `my-component`. By the way `select` is a native event, maybe it conflicts with your code. Try to change your event to another name that does not make conflict